# A model for conformal structures on polygon

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, conformal-geometry, teichmueller-theory

By a conformal structure on a polygon, I mean all the vertices of a polygon are missing (or, equivalently, it has ideal vertices), so that it can be considered as a conformal structure on the unit disk which has on the boundary unit circle marked points corresponding to the vertices of the polygon(This is just a simple application of the uniformization theorem). And there's yet another model for this that often appears in literature;

[image]

The above is a model for a 7-gon of which I took a snapshot from [Baldwin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.3293.pdf). Here each half-infinite band corresponds to a neighborhood of the vertices of the 7-gon, and there exist segments perpendicular to the "edges of the polygon" which is shown as the curves bounding the polygon and also as the height of rectangular regions in the diagram above. Then the conformal structures on the given 7-gon is parametrized by $I_1$ to $I_4$, which are the height of rectangular regions. Of course, we assume that there exist perpendiculars for every pair of edges of the polygon, and you have freedom to choose which 4 disjoint perpendiculars (($n-3$) such perpendiculars in $n$-gon in general) to parametrize the conformal structures.

The claim that I want to verify is that this indeed parametrizes all the conformal structures on a given polygon, and thus that the dimension of the moduli space of conformal structures of $n$-gon is precisely $n-3$ as expected. It is not even obvious to me that this parametrization is surjective though. Any idea or suggestion of references is appreciated.

---

Edit. After the discussion with Moishe Cohen, it seems not true in general that this parametrization is surjective. And it seems this construction is somehow related to the Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates(though I have no proper knowledge on F-N in case of surfaces with boundary), so I would appreciate a suggestion of reference of F-N coordinates relevant to this model(i.e., disk with marked points on boundary).

Comment: I am surprised by this construction appearing "often", where else did you see it? In the case when one has tripods  instead of hexagons, this is indeed standard, once you double the surface (to get a punctured sphere). A reference that I know and like is "Quadratic Differentials" by Strebel. In this case indeed you get a diffeomoirphic parameterization of the moduli space. Maybe the same proof can be adopted to hexagons.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Actually I don't get what you mean by hexagons, maybe it should be heptagon? BTW, I guess it might be because of my background; I believe most texts about floer theory do like this description. And now that I think of, this must be related to the Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates of disk with marked points. I wonder there exists a good exposition of this, considering I learnt F-N in the case of closed surfaces and hasn't heard of it in case of surfaces with boundary.

Comment: Remove all the rectangles from your picture, what's left are the hexagons.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I can only see a hexagon at the center, and the others seems tetra- and pentagons. And I now see why you mention hexagons, as its doubling constitutes pair of pants that parametrize the Teichmuller space via F-N, isn't it?

Comment: Right. The rest of the hexagons are degenerate since some vertices are at infinity, but if you chop them off (as in your picture!) they become true hexagons..

Comment: With some work (a la Strebel) one can show that this "parameterization" is injective, but it is not going to be surjective. I find it weird that people use it.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Hmm, I see. If it is not surjective, then I guess they use this without harm because this parametrization covers the boundary of Teichmuller space, and this is the only problematic case to be considered. (They indeed cook up a map from this Teichmuller space times a point in the polygon to some contractible space (which is the space of complex structures of another space) and do some homotopy theory.)

Comment: Yes, it covers everything but a compact region.